# 14.04 Loud Constant Fan After Upgrade - Thinkpad W500

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, thinkpad, fan

I had an excellent experience on Ubuntu 14.04.3 - quiet and efficient. I pressed OK to the system updates. Ever since I did that, the fan runs non-stop and quite loud from the second I logged in, with no break at all.

First, it would be nice to fix that.
But, is it possible (and safe), to revert back to pre upgrade state?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was reinstall 14.04 but this time I did not update - this is not optimal but the fans are quiet again.